# How to Put a SkAction to the End of another one?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So for example I have a block that moves 2 seconds to the left side but before you can see him stop after two seconds there is a fadeOut Animation which is 0.2 seconds long and will start running after theblock has moved for 1.8 seconds, i tried to manage it somehow with a Group or a Sequence but it didn't work, so how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `SKAction.sequence` and `SKAction.group` to create two actions that run in parallel.  One of those actions will be a sequence that combines the wait and fade:

```
let pause = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.8)
let fade = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 0.2)
let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0, duration: 2)

// sequence creates an action that runs a collection
// of actions sequentially (one after the other)
// pause 1.8 seconds, and then fade for 0.2 seconds
let pauseAndFade = SKAction.sequence([pause, fade])

// group creates an action that runs a collection of
// actions in parallel (at the same time)
// run move and pauseAndFade in parallel
let moveAndFade = SKAction.group([move, pauseAndFade])
```

The `moveAndFade` action will do what you want: move the block to the left for 2 seconds and fade out over the last 0.2 seconds of that move.